# Rational number and irrational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are 197 different non-zero real numbers, and the sum of any two **distinct** numbers is a rational number or the product is a rational number. Prove that: 197 numbers, each square is a rational number.

The number 197 is not important, so I can assume that there are only 10 numbers to make the question sounds easier:

- when all of the 10 numbers are rational, then their square must be rational.
- Now I assume that there is a irrational number *a* . Then, the remaining 9 numbers can be either *p* - *a* or *p* / *a*, while *p* is a rational number.

However, if there will not be three number like *p* - *a*. let *b*<sub>1</sub> = *p*<sub>1</sub> - *a*,  *b*<sub>2</sub> = *p*<sub>2</sub> - *a* and *b*<sub>3</sub> = *p* - *a*, then b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> = *p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>2</sub> - 2*a*, which is not a rational number, so b<sub>1</sub>  b<sub>2</sub> = *p*<sub>1</sub>*p*<sub>2</sub> - *a*(*p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>2</sub>) + a<sup>2</sup> must be rational number. *b*<sub>2</sub>*b*<sub>3</sub> and *b*<sub>1</sub>*b*<sub>3</sub> must also be rational number.
Therefore, *p*<sub>1</sub>*p*<sub>2</sub> - *a*(*p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>2</sub>) + a<sup>2</sup>, *p*<sub>2</sub>*p*<sub>3</sub> - *a*(*p*<sub>2</sub> + *p*<sub>3</sub>)+ a<sup>2</sup> , *p*<sub>1</sub>*p*<sub>3</sub> - *a*(*p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>3</sub>)+ a<sup>2</sup> are rational numbers. p * p is absolutely a rational number, so *A*<sub>0</sub> = - *a*(*p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>2</sub>) + a<sup>2</sup>, *A*<sub>1</sub> = - *a*(*p*<sub>2</sub> + *p*<sub>3</sub>)+ *a*<sup>2</sup> , *A*<sub>2</sub> = - *a*(*p*<sub>1</sub> + *p*<sub>3</sub>)+ a<sup>2</sup>, A is rational number, *A*<sub>2</sub> -*A*<sub>1</sub> = *a*(*p*<sub>2</sub> - *p*<sub>1</sub>), *p*<sub>2</sub> - *p*<sub>1</sub> can only be 0, which contradicts that every number is different.

This shows that there are at most 2 numbers like p - a, and there must be at least 8 numbers like p / a. However I didn't know how to continue the proof, anyone can help me?

Comment: "Proof-verification" is a tag used for questions about the validity of a certain proof. Since you have provided no proof, this would hardly be an appropriate tag. Also, it is customary here to convince the readers that you have put in some effort in order to solve the problem, so that the general spirit of the site is a true discussion of mathematical ideas, and not a "do-my-homework" service taken advantage of by lazy students who will never get anywhere anyway.

Comment: @MattiP. - and it fulfills the conclusion too, so what are you saying?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. If I have a list $1, 2, 3, \ldots , 196, 197$, it fulfills the requirements ...

Comment: @MattiP.  ditto .The assumption is that in this set of $197$ numbers, given any two, either their product or their sum is rational. You are required to prove that for each of the $197$ numbers, its square is rational.

Comment: As I read it, we have a list $a_1,\ldots,a_{197}$ of distinct nonzero reals, for each $i$ and $j$ either $a_i+a_j\in\Bbb Q$ or $a_ia_j\in\Bbb Q$, and the problem is to prove each $a_i^2\in\Bbb Q$. I'm not sure whether or not $i=j$ is excluded in the condition....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Obviously $i=j$ is excluded.

Comment: @ uniqesolution: are you sure that $i=j$ is excluded ? If yes, why ?

Comment: @Fred: because that makes the problem trivial.

Comment: @Yves: yes it make the problem trivial, see my answer.

Comment: @Fred: this is why it is unlikely that $i=j$ is allowed in the problem statement.

Comment: I know that the question is not clear enough, I've already updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set - call it $S$ - contains one rational number, say $r$, then all of the numbers are rational, for if $x \in S\setminus \{r\}$ such that $r + x = p \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $x = p-r \in \mathbb{Q}$, and if $x \in S\setminus \{r\}$ is such that $r\cdot x = p \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $x = \frac{p}{r} \in \mathbb{Q}$. In that case, it is clear that all squares are rational.

So we can assume that all elements of $S$ are irrational. For each $\alpha \in S$, there are at most two elements of $S$ whose sum with $\alpha$ is rational. For if there were three or more, say $\alpha + \beta = r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha + \gamma = s \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha + \delta = t \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\beta + \gamma = r+s - 2\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$, $\beta + \delta = r+t-2\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $\gamma + \delta = s+t - 2\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$, so by the assumption we would have $\beta\delta \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\gamma\delta \in \mathbb{Q}$, and consequently
$$(\beta - \gamma)\delta = (r-s)\delta \in \mathbb{Q}\,,$$
which by the irrationality of $\delta$ implies $r = s$ and thus $\beta = \gamma$, contradicting our assumption that $\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are distinct.

Thus, if $S$ contains at least $7$ elements, then for every $\alpha \in S$ there are $\beta,\gamma\in S$ such that $\alpha\beta, \alpha\gamma, \beta\gamma$ are all rational. (Picking $\alpha$ excludes at most two numbers, and then choosing $\beta$ excludes at most two more.) But then $\beta = \frac{r}{\alpha}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\gamma = \frac{s}{\beta} = \frac{s}{r}\alpha$ for some $s\in \mathbb{Q}$, whence $$\alpha^2 = \frac{r}{s}\alpha\gamma \in \mathbb{Q}\,.$$

Actually, we can lower the cardinality required in this argument.

For $\alpha \in S$, let $E(\alpha) = \{x \in S : x\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$. This is the set excluded by $\alpha$ in the above argument, and before that we saw that $E(\alpha)$ contains at most two elements, since $E(\alpha) \subseteq \{ x \in S : x + \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. This yields the trivial bound $\operatorname{card}\bigl(E(\alpha) \cup E(\beta)\bigr) \leqslant 4$ if $\beta \in S\setminus E(\alpha)$ used above. But in fact, we have the bound $\operatorname{card}\bigl(E(\alpha) \cup E(\beta)\bigr) \leqslant 3$. For if $\alpha\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha + x = r \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $x\beta = (r-\alpha)\beta = r\beta - \alpha\beta$ is irrational unless $r -\alpha= 0$, i.e. $x = -\alpha$. So if $E(\alpha)$ contains two elements, at least one of them also belongs to $E(\beta)$. And $E(\alpha) \cup E(\beta)$ can only contain three elements if $-\alpha \in E(\alpha)$ and $-\beta \in E(\beta)$. So we can unconditionally lower the required cardinality to $6$, and we can lower it to $5$ under the condition that $S$ contains at most one pair of negatives.

We cannot lower the required cardinality further, because for any irrational $x$ whose square is also irrational, the set
$$S = \{x, -x, x^{-1}, -x^{-1}\}$$
has the property that for each pair of distinct elements either the sum or the product is rational, but none of the squares of the elements is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be one of these numbers. Then $a^2 \in \mathbb Q$ or $2a \in \mathbb Q$.

In the first case we are done. In the second case we have $4a^2 \in \mathbb Q$, hence $a^2 \in \mathbb Q$.